# Javascript documentation in the MSDN library?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, msdn

I am using Visual Studio 2010 (Visual Web Developer) and I have installed through the "Help Library Manager" (Help->Manage Help Settings) all the documentation that seems to be related to web development and "JScript". And despite this, there doesn't seem to be any documentation on javascript itself installed. Search for getElementById for example and you get everything except information about the javascript function itself.

Online MSDN has the javascript doc, how to add it offline?

Comment: Thanks guys. Especially for Package This

Answer (score 0):

JScript is Microsoft's implementation of JavaScript without the user of the trademarked word "Java".

`getElementById` is not part of JavaScript. It is a [DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/) method. Browsers expose a DOM API to their client side scripting environments. You probably need to find DOM documentation if it doesn't appear in the JScript docs.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Package This](http://packagethis.codeplex.com/). You can select what help files you want to download for offline reading from the MSDN Library (as well as TechNet and MSDN Content Service). You might be able to download the javascript docs from there via the MSDN library.